# Data formatting, splitting objects & deleting key's/values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am quite bad at data manipulation and after a lot of time I was finally able to get it working how I wanted. The thing is I don't like all the delete operations, I think the code can be a lot cleaner and the runtime seems somewhat slow on a lot of data. Code readability is very important here but it needs to be small, contained and fast. ES6+ i welcome and of course so are tips and general information.

### Input Data:

```
{
  agency: "",
  agent: "",
  agent_email: "",
  agent_phone: "",
  date_of_birth: "2007-05-30",
  delivery_address: "address - 1",
  delivery_city: "city - 1",
  delivery_country: "PE",
  delivery_state: "state - 1",
  delivery_zipcode: "zip_code - 1",
  facebook: "",
  instagram: "",
  name: "Dustin Peter",
  primary_email: "wagnerpeter@bailey-schroeder.example.com",
  primary_phone_number: "+31622064234",
  residential_address: "address - 0",
  residential_city: "city - 0",
  residential_country: "LC",
  residential_state: "state - 0",
  residential_zipcode: "zip_code - 0",
  secondary_email: "garzajustin@vasquez.example.com",
  secondary_phone_number: "+39349330249",
  shoe_size: "38"
  snapchat: "",
  twitter: "",
  url: "",
  youtube: "",
}
```

### End Result:

**Data Set 1:**

```
{
  name: "Dustin Peter",
  primary_email: "wagnerpeter@bailey-schroeder.example.com",
  primary_phone_number: "+31622064234",
}
```

**Data Set 2:**

```
{
  date_of_birth: "2007-05-30",
  delivery_address: {
    address: "address - 1",
    city: "city - 1",
    country: "PE",
    state: "state - 1",
    zip_code: "zip_code - 1",
  }
  residential_address: {
    address: "address - 0",
    city: "city - 0",
    country: "LC",
    state: "state - 0",
    zip_code: "zip_code - 0",
  }
  secondary_email: "garzajustin@vasquez.example.com",
  secondary_phone_number: "+39349330249",
  shoe_size: "38",
}
```

### My Working Code:

```
const dataSet1 = {
  name: data.name,
  primary_email: data.primary_email,
  primary_phone_number: data.primary_phone_number,
};

const dataSet2 = {};
Object.keys(data).forEach((prop) => {
    if (data[prop]) { dataSet2[prop] = data[prop]; }
});

dataSet2.residential_address = {
    address: dataSet2.residential_address,
    city: dataSet2.residential_city,
    country: dataSet2.residential_country,
    state: dataSet2.residential_state,
    zip_code: dataSet2.residential_zipcode,
};

dataSet2.delivery_address = {
    address: dataSet2.delivery_address,
    city: dataSet2.delivery_city,
    country: dataSet2.delivery_country,
    state: dataSet2.delivery_state,
    zip_code: dataSet2.delivery_zipcode,
};

delete dataSet2.name;
delete dataSet2.primary_email;
delete dataSet2.primary_phone_number;
delete dataSet2.residential_city;
delete dataSet2.residential_country;
delete dataSet2.residential_state;
delete dataSet2.residential_zip_code;
delete dataSet2.delivery_city;
delete dataSet2.delivery_country;
delete dataSet2.delivery_state;
delete dataSet2.delivery_zip_code;
```

Comment: These are not real names, not, and/or email addresses, are they? In the case they are, please delete the question, anonymize that data and post a new one

Comment: Nop, they are random data generated in our server.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.entries()` and `.filter()` with `RegExp` `/date|delivery|residential|secondary|shoe/` and `.test()` to filter data from `data`, create a function expecting property name and optional separator character to concatenate to property name to replace in returned object spread as values passed to second parameter of `Object.assign()`

```js
const data = {
  agency: "",
  agent: "",
  agent_email: "",
  agent_phone: "",
  date_of_birth: "2007-05-30",
  delivery_address: "address - 1",
  delivery_city: "city - 1",
  delivery_country: "PE",
  delivery_state: "state - 1",
  delivery_zipcode: "zip_code - 1",
  facebook: "",
  instagram: "",
  name: "Dustin Peter",
  primary_email: "wagnerpeter@bailey-schroeder.example.com",
  primary_phone_number: "+31622064234",
  residential_address: "address - 0",
  residential_city: "city - 0",
  residential_country: "LC",
  residential_state: "state - 0",
  residential_zipcode: "zip_code - 0",
  secondary_email: "garzajustin@vasquez.example.com",
  secondary_phone_number: "+39349330249",
  shoe_size: "38",
  snapchat: "",
  twitter: "",
  url: "",
  youtube: ""
}

let [filters, filtered] = [
  ['date', 'delivery', 'residential', 'secondary', 'shoe']
, (data, props) => Object.entries(data)
  .filter(([key, value]) =>
    new RegExp(props.join`|`)
    .test(key))
];
  
const handleProps = (prop, r = '', props = filtered(data, filters)) => 
  ([...p] = props.filter(([key, value]) => 
    new RegExp(prop).test(key)).map(([key, value]) => 
    (r ? {[key.replace(new RegExp(prop + r), '')]: value} : value))
    , r ? p : p.pop());

const dataSet2 = {
 date_of_birth:handleProps('date_of_birth')
, delivery_address: Object.assign({}, ...handleProps('delivery', '_'))
, residential_address: Object.assign({}, ...handleProps('residential', '_'))
, secondary_email: handleProps('secondary_email')
, secondary_phone_number: handleProps('secondary_phone_number')
, shoe_size: handleProps('shoe_size')
};
               
console.log(dataSet2);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this?

1. Define a regular expression to extract `delivery_address` and `residential_address`.
2. Define `dataSet1` and `dataSet2` so you can fill them later.
3. Store *primary values* into `dataSet1` and delete them from `data`, since you don’t need them anymore.
4. Loop through the properties of the `data` object and store non-empty values into `dataSet2`. If the property matches the regular expression, store its value in the appropriate address sub-object. Otherwise store it *directly* to `dataSet2`.

**Ready example:**

```
const addr_rgxp = /^(delivery|residential)_(\w+)$/,
    dataSet1 = {},
    dataSet2 = {
        residential_address: {},
        delivery_address: {}
    };

for (let prop of ['name', 'primary_email', 'primary_phone_number']) {
    dataSet1[prop] = data[prop];
    delete data[prop];
}

for (let prop in data) {
    if (data[prop]) {
        let m = prop.match(addr_rgxp);
        if (m) {
            let addr_type = m[1] + '_address';
            dataSet2[addr_type][m[2]] = data[prop];
        } else {
            dataSet2[prop] = data[prop];
        }
    }
}
```